# Want to add line to file using PrintWriter class in Java. File created, data isn't saved

Tags: java, file, stream, makefile, printwriter

I want my program to create a new text file unless one already exists. Any way, I want to print one line to the file for each time the program is run. The file is created but no data is saved to it. Why?

```
File fileName = new File("fileName");

try {
    if (fileName.exists())
    {
        filePrinter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    }
    else
    {
        filePrinter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName, true));
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

//irrelevant code


filePrinter.println("some text" + integerValue + "then more text");
filePrinter.close();
```

Comment: what is lifeStatisticsFile ?

Comment: it was a remnant of the original code, i changed the names before posting here. It's now changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend flushing out the content before closing it.

```
filePrinter.flush();
```

if this doesnt work try the following:

```
filePrinter = new FileWriter(new File(fileName));
filePrinter.write("some text" + integerValue + "then more text");
filePrinter.flush();
filePrinter.close();
```

Comment: I did, but it doesn't change the result. the file fileName is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was outside the posted code, all apologies. The problem was that the

```
    //irrelevant code
```

Contained instructions to reset the program upon certain conditions. Those conditions were always true, and so the filePrinter.println() code was never reached.

Thank you for all input.